# Insert Ad element into foreach loop every 4 instances

Tags: php, loops, cakephp, foreach

I am adding in feed Ads to my website. I have a foreach statement that creates a list of posts. I have created a counter that is supposed to count every four posts and insert the Ad content then repeat.

I have tried some other iterations of this but this is the one I can actually get to do something. I can find a lot of info on this exact thing pertaining to wordpress. But I am running cake php and would prefer a pure php solution.

```
    <?php
    $count = 1;
    foreach($stories as $story) {
            echo '<h2><a href="'.BASE_URL.'/'.$story->slug.'">'.$story->title.'</a></h2>';
            if(!empty($story->excerpt)) {
                echo $story->excerpt;
            } else {
                echo limit_text($story->body);
            }
            if ($count % 4 == 1) {
                echo AD_SENSE_INFEED;
            }
    }
    $count++;
    ?>
```

This code is what I currently have but its not working the way I would like it to. As if now it basically goes every other. So POST, AD, POST AD...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't a coding problem, its a math problem. What you're using is called modulos or remainders basically.

So that said:

```
if ($count % 4 == 1) {
```

For it to equal 1 we have to feed in something that goes in evenly once and leaves one more.

What you want to do is:

```
if ($count % 4 == 0) {
```

Aka it means there's no remainder, 4 goes into it evenly with nothing left over.

As @RiggsFolly mentioned and I completely missed this(Give his comment a up vote) your $count variable should be incremented inside the loop as well otherwise it will only increment once after the loop ends.

Comment: But it would REALLY REALLY help if the `$count++;` was inside the loop and not OUTSIDE of it

Comment: Good catch, I only noticed the first problem, i'll add it to the answer so it's clear to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of count all together (and just use the numeric index of the array)

```
//just some "test" data
$stories = array_fill(0, 100, []);

foreach( $stories as $count => $story) {
    echo $count." ".($count % 4)."\n";

    if ($count % 4 == 3) {
        echo "--------------------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
--------------------------------------
4 0
5 1
6 2
7 3
--------------------------------------
...
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70e53901e576ca14258e78896059d71ca060f600)

If your not sure if the keys are in proper order, you can reset them:

```
foreach(array_values($stories) as $count => $story) {
```

Obviously an array starts at `0`, so you have to offset the `%` result a bit ... lol ... Yes I am to lazy to increment.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I see your using `array_fill`. The number of elements you set here is 100. Is there a way with this to not have a set number of elements. So all the posts in the database get shown, not just 100. I am reading its a mandatory parameter.

Comment: That was just for example data... you don't / shouldn't use that part.  @see `//just some "test" data`  I just used that so I could do a visual representation in the output with the lines etc....

Comment: Ahh, I see. You were just it using to create the example array, mine already exists. Is there an advantage to using the numeric index? I always find different ways of accomplishing the same thing with coding and am always curious as to to advantages of each.

Comment: Only it has less moving parts to worry about, its cleaner in other words as it doesn't require you to manage a separate variable for a counter..  For example if you decided to move this loop you wouldn't need to worry about "missing something"  (something being the extra variable for the counter)